# Adding Filter Logic On Custom Action - Salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq

We have a use case where in we have to filter out products based on advance condition
In Custom Action , we can add search filters with index 1,2,3.... etc.
Unlike in Approval Rules (Advanced Approval managed Package) we can add filter logic with custom condition, is there facility available to add advance filter logic in Custom Action of Salesforce CPQ package.
Please suggest and advice.
[image] 
[image]